# Por que me da error Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy intentado enviar emails en laravel:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=micorreo@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=miclave
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

cuando intento el registro me da este error:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

y esta función es la que me marca:

```
public function startTLS()
    {
        // STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT only allow tls1.0 connections (some php versions)
        // To support modern tls we allow explicit tls1.0, tls1.1, tls1.2
        // Ssl3 and older are not allowed because they are vulnerable
        // @TODO make tls arguments configurable
        return stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->stream, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_0_CLIENT | STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_1_CLIENT | STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT);
    }
```

Comment: Es por la seguridad de gmail. Debes configurar la cuenta gmail para aceptar el acceso a "aplicaciones menos seguras". Te recomendaría usar otro servidor de correo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, cual me recomiendas?

Comment: Yo usé mail.ru para hacer mis pruebas, pero puedes usar cualquiera que te ofrezca servicio SMTP.

Comment: Si muchas gracias, estoy intentando con mailtrap.io. Gracias.